# Rails/rspec, integration test fail with "no route matches" but route does exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, integration-testing

I am doing some simple integration testing. I want to test the sold_items action in the users controller. I have confirmed that the route exists and returns json  by accessing it from the browser. However, rspec is telling me that the route doesn't exist. PLease see below, the spec, the error, and my route.rb. Thanks!

spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #items" do
    it "returns http success" do
            user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            get "users/#{user.id}/sold_items"
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

end
```

fail message:

```
  1) UsersController GET #items returns http success
     Failure/Error: get "users/#{user.id}/sold_items"

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"users/10/sold_items", :controller=>"users"}
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


    resources :users
    resources :items
    get "users/:id/sold_items" => "users#sold_items"
```

---

EDIT

spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #items" do
    it "returns http success" do
            user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            get "users/:id/sold_items", id: user.id

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

end
```

failure message

```
  2) UsersController GET #items returns http success
     Failure/Error: get "users/:id/sold_items", id: user.id

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"users/:id/sold_items", :controller=>"users", :id=>"12"}
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

EDIT.2 MarvC second suggestion

require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, type: [:request, :controller] do

  describe "GET #items" do
    it "returns http success" do
            user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            get "/users/:id/sold_items", id: user.id


      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

end
```

failure

looks like the user.id isn't being passed in properly here

```
  2) UsersController GET #items returns http success
     Failure/Error: @sold_items = User.find(params[:id]).seller_items.sold

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find User with 'id'=:id
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:6:in `sold_items'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

One Solution:
when I use string interpolation to pass user.id into the url it works...

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: [:request, :controller] do

  describe "GET #items" do
    it "returns http success" do
            user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            get "users/#{user.id}/sold_items", id: user.id


      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your syntax is wrong.

**change:**
        `get "users/#{user.id}/sold_items"`

**To:**

**rails 4**

`get "users/:id/sold_items", id: user.id`

**rails 5**
`get "users/:id/sold_items", params: { id: user.id }`

Comment: I implemented the syntax you suggested from rails 4, please see the EDIT. spec is still failing with no route matches error

Comment: try adding `:request`: in `RSpec.describe UsersController, type: [:request, :controller] do`

Comment: I was able to get it to work with :request. However, I had to use string interpolation. Please see Edit.2

Comment: You do not need to call out the 'users' part of the get because you are inside the context of the UserController already.. Try something like: `get :sold_items, id: user.id` perhaps

Comment: thanks jaydel. I actually had to remove :resources to get your suggested syntax to work

Comment: you might consider putting the route for sold_items IN the user resources definition. checkout "2.10 Adding More RESTful Actions" on this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html